# ping github.organization.com returns unknown host

Tags: github, docker, containers

When I try to ping github.com it responds back with replies. However, pinging github.organizationname.com returns "ping:unknown host github.organizationname.com. This is an organization account so not sure if anything related to ssh keys or firewall.

Any suggestions??

Comment: Why would you expect that to work?  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Not sure if docker related. are you trying to access to organizationname.github.io instead ?